# Isolate Virtual Machines on host-only adapter

Tags: malware, virtualization

I am performing malware analysis on VirtualBox. I want the VMs to only communicate with each other. Using host-only adapters, I have installed a Windows 7 VM (192.168.56.101) with the default gateway (192.168.56.102) and a REMnux VM (192.168.56.102).

My host machine is running on IP 192.168.1.3. But I am able to ping both the VMs. How can I prove that the virtual machine is isolated and does not have access to my host machine? Are there any steps that I can show to demonstrate isolation?

Or should I use internal network? But for some reason, when I use internal network my REMnux machine is not getting any ip address.

Comment: This is more of a networking question. But I'm fairly certain you will need to use static IP addresses on the internal networks.

Answer (score 1):

If you put `host-only`, your VMs can access, well, only the host. Your host machine is not isolated, but the opposite: it's the only machine they can access.

To isolate the VMs, you must use **Internal Network**. Using this network means:

- The host can't access the guests
- Guests can't access the host
- Guests can't access the internet
- Guests can access each other

If you use Host Only, the guests access the host. If you use NAT or bridge, they can access your entire network.